# Django multiple user group design method

Tags: django

I have a project for a staffing service company that has at least four user groups (admin, employers, employees and the owner of the staffing service company). Each of them has the following functions:

1. Admin can do everything.
2. Employers (different companies) can publish, update, view the job/gag events. (can't delete without admin's permission).
3. Employees can view, confirm/update after finishing the events.
4. Owners/stakeholders are pretty much similar to admin. Perhaps do not have delete permission.

BTW,  admin and owner could be the same person/group if it would be simpler. I have read some blogs and some of them mentioned to use AbstractUser subclass, etc. However, I still feel not clear enough. Should I build an app called User which has three or four classes in that model.py in User App?

Those four classes would be "Class Admin", "Class Owner", "Class Emoloyee", "Class Employer"? Or how should I implement it? Any advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Django permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/)

Or you can add a type field in your user model and give permissions to your view based on type of the user like:

```
if request.user.type == "employee":
    return Response("Permission denied", status = 403)
```

now if user type is "employee" it will not have access to this view

Comment: thanks for your answer @mohammadh-rzn. I would like to have more details about how to create those user classes. After that, maybe permissions :)

Comment: you could inherit your class from abstractbaseuser and permissions and you are good to go for more details you can check source code of  user model of django.contrib.auth.models hope it helps